# Setting AlarmManager events following Boot event

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have this receiver for handling BOOT_COMPLETED event:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
     SystemUtills.scadualeAlarmManagerFromTable(context);
   }
}
```

No problem so far, my receiver catches the BOOT_COMPLETED event and start the method "scadualeAlarmManagerFromTable(context)".

Inside the method i am doing among others:

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, Long.getLong(time), pendingIntent);
```

The problem is that alarmManager  is null at this point. why is that?
(i didnt post all the code take in notice that time, and pendingIntent params are set).

Comment: Is there any error? If there, can you post log message?

Comment: Based on my experience, there should be no problem with your code (I did the same way to get `AlarmManager`). If possible, post more related code.